# Point Biserial Correlation

Tags: correlation, normality-assumption, robust

In terms of testing the assumption of normality for a Point Biserial Correlation;
I have a dichotomous variable (1 = microsleep, 0 = no microsleep)
and a continuous variable (number of driving events occurring per drive)

My continuous variable has alot of 0 values (i.e. no event occurring that drive)

My shapiro wilk statistic was significant for no micro-sleeps, but not significant for micro-sleeps (skew and kurtosis all within + - 2). Homogeneity of variance was non-significant.

My question is, how robust is the point-biserial correlation including its significance test for normality violations? References for the finding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can find something [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=point-biserial+correlation+answers%3A1)